# How to set particular pin for WiFi Direct connection?

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct

Trying to setup connection with particular PIN code:

```
WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
config.deviceAddress = assetWifiP2pDevice.deviceAddress;
config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.DISPLAY;
config.wps.pin = "00000000";
mManager.cancelConnect(mChannel, null);
mManager.connect(mChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int reason) {
    }
});
```

but on popup connection dialog i see random generated PIN.

What is proper way to setup pin and do automatic connection without any dialogs on both sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by just changing setup to WpsInfo.KEYPAD

```
WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
config.deviceAddress = assetWifiP2pDevice.deviceAddress;
config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.KEYPAD;
config.wps.pin = "00000000";
mManager.cancelConnect(mChannel, null);
mManager.connect(mChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int reason) {
    }
});
```

Comment: So were you able to bypass the dialog? I have been trying it for sometime unsuccessfully. Also isn't WPS for 120 secs only?

Comment: Yes, dialog is bypassing. About WPS - i even don't press WPS button. Maybe this is device specific. My device (Digi WVA) haves two modes for WiFi Direct: 1) connecting via press button 2) setuping PIN code on device and using this code during connection.

Comment: So basically you use a hardcoded wps pin to connect? will have to check this out

Comment: How do you set the pin in the device? I know how set pin to connect to device

Comment: How do you know the pin code. For example is "00000000"?

Comment: Antariksha Yelkawar, Slim_user71169: pin code may be setted vie web configuration. Details in http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/html/90001929/90001929_D/Files/configuration.html

See "Configure WVA for Wi-Fi Direct" section there